# Debugging in C programming

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I'm new to the Debugging approach, and there are many things I can not understand.

## The main question here I wanna confirm if my image file contain my source code then anyone can get the source code using debugging feature like list command .

Debugging is used for image files , like exe extensions

and I see some commands in gdb like "list command"

if I can list all my source code is  this is safe and secure,I mean debugger will be able to see all my code.

if my code compiled as a release version, list command still able to show all my source code?

Also what is the benefit of debugging, I mean I can use testing unit testing , destruction testing or whatever.

so why exactly debugging. and what is the use to know the faults of my software after it is already compiled.

finally can I use debugging on source code itself?

briefly I wanna know the core need to debugging.

I'm sure this will get many down votes, but I do not mind if I can understand the core need of debugging.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert is a good summary on, well, how to debug your programs. :)

Comment: You don't understand why it's useful to step-by-step examine the execution of something complex that runs almost at the speed of light, and has billions of possible states?

Comment: As for what it *is*, well... It's a way to find and help fix [software *bugs*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bug). To **de**-bug the code is to remove bugs. Knowing how to debug your code, including such different techniques such as *rubber duck debugging* and actually using a debugger program, it is crucial and necessary knowledge for any one who wants to be a programmer, even on a hobbyist level.

Comment: my image file always contain my source code ?

Comment: No your executable program will usually not include the source code, but there might be *debug information* that contains information about where the source might be.

Comment: Unit testing tells you whether your code meets a requirement or returns expected values for a given set of inputs.  It doesn't tell you *what to fix* if the test fails or the wrong values get returned.  The essence of debugging is tracing through the program logic to look for mistakes.  Tools like gdb execute your code a step at a time, allowing you to check the state of variables between each statement, or to verify that a statement is getting executed (or not), etc.  The source code itself is not part of the image, but the image is built such that it can reference the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, any C application will be compiled down to machine code. This must always contain the program logic to function correctly. It is still difficult to decompile your machine code back to the original source since much information (like variable names etc) is lost during the compilation and linking phases.

In order for a debugger to provide all the necessary info on variable names and sometimes even exact source code, the necessary information must be written somewhere during the compilation process. For ELF executables, this is by default written in a format called DWARF in a separate ELF section. For this to happen you must compile your application with the -g option (gcc). Using tools like `objcopy` and `strip` you can remove the debug sections and store them in a separate file is so desired.

This is useful for debugging and also reporting what went wrong if your application crashes in the form of a `core` file (hence the term core dump).

Removing debug info provides some security but will not deter a determined adversary from reverse engineering your source code.

Comment: In the C tag, your first sentence is correct.  In other tags (Java, Python, Perl, C#, Swift, …) it is easily arguably not correct.  Since this is a C question, it isn't a problem (though maybe 'any application written in C' would avoid any need for this comment.  Although there are (or were) some C interpreters, they are in a vanishingly tiny minority and can substantially be ignored.)

Comment: The details of my answer are also specific to unixes that use the ELF file format. But it is tagged GDB